# How to I remove an entry widget when pressing backspace

Tags: python, list, tkinter

I'm making a program so that people can enter their names. How can make it so that when I press backspace, an entry widget gets removed?

```
from tkinter import*
import time
import sys
master = Tk()
master.title('Tournament Software')
master.geometry("800x800")
master.configure(background="black")
entryList = list()
def end():
    master.destroy()
def click1():
    master.destroy()
    master1 = Tk()
    master1.title("Tournament Software")
    master1.geometry("800x800")
    master1.configure(background="black")
    la=Label(master1, text="Enter Contestant Names:",font="none 50 bold", fg="white", bg="black").pack()
    lab=Label(master1, text="Press Enter For More Contestants",font="none 10 bold", fg="white",bg="black").pack()
    def enter_event1(event):
        entryList.append(Entry(master1,bd=5,width=50))
        entryList[-1].pack()
        print(entryList)
    def back_event(event):
        #don't know what to put here.
    e=Entry(master1, bd=5,width=50).pack()
    master1.bind("<Return>", enter_event1)
    master1.bind("<BackSpace>", back_event)
l=Label(master, text="Tournament Software", font="none 50 bold", bg="black", fg="white").pack()
b=Button(master, text="Start",font="none 50 bold",command = click1).pack(side=LEFT)
b1=Button(master, text="Quit",font="none 55 bold",command = end).pack(side=RIGHT)
mainloop()
```

Comment: Do you want the entry in which the backspace was pressed to be destroyed? And the players might want to hit backspace to correct the spelling, so I guess that you want to remove the entry only if it is empty. Am I right?

Comment: yes, or you can make the key shift or anything else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`event.widget` is the widget in which the event occurred, here it is the entry in which the key was pressed.

So to destroy an entry when backspace is pressed only if it is empty you can use:

```
def back_event(event):
    if not event.widget.get():
        # the entry is empty
        event.widget.destroy()
```